# javascript converting javascript text into date object "Invalid date"

Tags: javascript, date

I have several dates in this text format:

```
var date = "March 12th 2015, 8:37:29 pm";
```

I want to get a date object but I am getting invalid date when creating the date object.

I tried just doing:

```
var date_o = new Date(date);
```

No success. Also tried:

```
  var at = Date.parse(date.replace(/[ap]m$/i, ''));
  if(date.match(/pm$/i) >= 0) {
     at += 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
  var date_o = new Date(at);
```

No success. What would be the correct way?

I think I should tell the date object that will get a string with `"format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')"`. Is this possible?

Comment: You date text should in either format described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your wish , use the construction function to get the date :

```
var date = "March 12th 2015, 8:37:29 pm";

function getDate(str){
    var monthList = ['January','February','March','April','May'
        ,'June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    var year = str.slice(11,15);
    var month = monthList.indexOf(str.slice(0,5));
    var day = str.slice(6,8);

    var isAm = str.slice(str.length-2);
    var hour = isAm == 'am' ? +str.slice(17,18) + 12:str.slice(17,18);
    var minute = str.slice(19,21);
    var second = str.slice(22,24);

    var date = new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);

    console.log(date)
    return date;

}

getDate(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong format for date. Just need remove `coma`, `th` and `AM/PM`.
So, input text must be like

```
var date = "March 12 2015 8:37:29";
```

So after that you can do

```
var date_o = new Date(date);
console.log(date_o instanceof Date); // ->true
```